# Unable to map application properties to object with dynamic property key

Tags: java, spring-boot, kotlin

I am trying to get application property object by value, i already did this in Java, but from some reason using Kotlin i can not manage to do it.

So basically what i have is list of application properties that looks like this:

```
ee.car.config.audi.serial=1
ee.car.config.audi.base=platform1

ee.car.config.bmw.serial=2
ee.car.config.bmw.base=platform2
```

so as you can see car identifiers (audi,bmw,peugeot,etc..) are dynamic, and i need simply by serial value to get object that represents the specific car and by car key(audi, bmw) to get all other properties.

And what i did is simple, i created configuration properties class like this:

```
@Configuration
@ConfigurationProperties(prefix = "ee.car")
data class FesEngineKeys(
        val config: HashMap<String, EeCarConfigParam> = HashMap()
) {
    fun getOrDefaultEEConfig(engineKey: String): EeCarConfigParam? {
        return config.getOrDefault(engineKey, config["audi"])
    }
```

And then object to map keys after dynamic value:

```
data class EeCarConfigParam {
        var serial: String,
        var base: String
}
```

But problem here is, in FesEngineKeys class, config property is empty, it looks like EeCarConfigParam can not be mapped.

Also interesting part is when i change:

```
val config: HashMap<String, EeCarConfigParam> = HashMap() to
val config: HashMap<String, String> = HashMap()
```

then i can see that config param is populated with all the values.

This code already works in Java and it looks like this:

```
@Configuration
@Getter
@Setter
@ConfigurationProperties(prefix = "ee.car")
public class FESEngineKeys {

    private Map<String, EeCarConfigParam> config = new HashMap<>();

    public EeCarConfigParam getOrDefaultEEConfig(String engineKey) {
        return config.getOrDefault(engineKey, config.get("audi"));
    }

    public EeCarConfigParam findBySerial(String serial) {
        return config.values().stream().filter(cfg -> cfg.getSerial().equalsIgnoreCase(serial)).findFirst().orElse(null);
    }

}


@Data
public class EeCarConfigParam {
    private String serial;
    private String base;
}
```

I really don't know why in the Kotlin case it is not working, i probably made some very basic mistake, and i would really appreciate if anyone can explain what is happening here

Comment: Two things, i would look after: first make EeCarConfigParam  a data class (for equals and hashcode) .. and second in kotlin the map is injected, while in java its a property .. changing the map to property? i guess the Map<String,String> i the spring default, which could be injected. its just guessing, maybe i am wrong

Comment: its already data class, my mistake i did not include that in question (its edited now).

What do you mean changing map to property ? Can you give example please ?

Comment: data class FesEngineKeys() {
private  val config: HashMap<String, EeCarConfigParam> = HashMap()    
....

Comment: Still not working

Comment: Making the config map public?

Comment: Tried that already... Not working

Comment: make val a var ?

Comment: yap already tried that too... its really annoying issue

Comment: yes the "magic" is always a little bit tricky .. in micronaut i need to use classes instead of data classes for the properties .. otherwise it will not work .. sorry, no more ideas ..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to handle this issue, it is somehow related to kotlin, because once when i instead of this:

```
data class EeCarConfigParam {
        var serial: String,
        var base: String
}
```

used "norma" Java class, everything started working, so all code from my question stays the same, only difference is this: instead of Kotlin EeCardConfigParam i created Java class like this:

```
public class EeCarConfigParam {
    private String publicUrl;
    private String base;
}
```

Note: with all default getters, setters, equals, hash and toString methods.

Answer (score 1):

Okay i got it.
According to that: https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/2.0.x/reference/html/boot-features-kotlin.html the support for what you want is very limited.

I made it working like that - not pretty nice :-( :

```
@ConfigurationProperties(prefix = "ee.car")
class FesEngineKeyProperties() {

    var config: MutableMap<String, EeCarConfigParam?>? = mutableMapOf()

    fun getBase(serial: String): String {
        if(config == null) return ""
        return config!!["audi"]?.base ?: ""
    }
}


class EeCarConfigParam() {
    lateinit var serial: String
    lateinit var base: String
}

@SpringBootApplication
@EnableConfigurationProperties(FesEngineKeyProperties::class)
class SandboxApplication

fun main(args: Array<String>) {
    runApplication<SandboxApplication>(*args)
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your effort and help, but i was able to do this on a more clean way, basically what i did is, i created "normal" Java class instead of Kotlin class, and everything is working without any extra or special code, tomorrow i will paste my solution, someone might find it useful.